# implement domain mapping

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, redirect, rewrite

I am working on a site which can have user portfolios.

The url we want to use is abc.mysite.com.

We want to give users to be able to purchase a domain name from us (we can integrate our system with domain reselling api).

My question is, how we can map the user domains like www.abc.com to our site abc.mysite.com

Thanks,
Ankur

Answer (score 0):

Do you have separate Apache virtual hosts for each `abc.mysite.com`?  I assume yes.

You can edit the virtual host configuration file, e.g. `abc.mysite.com.conf`, and add:

```
ServerAlias www.abc.com
```

And of course add a DNS `A` record.